# How to print elements in a vector c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am having trouble with my void print function to print out this vector. I'm not quite sure what it is talking about with "std::allocator. I get these errors:

```
st1.cpp: In function ‘void Print(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’:
st1.cpp:51: error: declaration of ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > v’ shadows a      parameter
```

Here is the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Initialize();
void Print();

int main()
{
stack<string> s1, s2;
s1.push("b");
s2.push("a");

if (s1.top() == s2.top())
{
    cout << "s1 == s2" << endl;
}
else if (s1.top() < s2.top())
{
    cout << "s1 < s2" << endl;
}
else if (s2.top() < s1.top())
{
    cout << "s2 < s1" << endl;
}
else 
{
    return 0;
}

vector<int> v;
Initialize();
Print();
}

void Initialize(vector<int> v)
{
int input;
cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
while(input != -1){
    cin >> input;
    v.push_back(input);
    //write_vector(v);
}
}

void Print (vector<int> v){
vector<int> v;
for (int i=0; i<v.size();i++){
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}
}
```

I just want to print v out to the screen. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at the place the compiler points you too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your function declaration and definition are not consistent, you want to generate vector from `Initialize`, you can do:

```
void Initialize(vector<int>& v);
```

To print vector:

```
void Print(const vector<int>& v);
```

Now you call:

```
vector<int> v;
Initialize(v);
Print(v);
```

Don't forget to change function definition of `Initialize`, `Print` to match the new signature I provided above.
Also you are redefining a local variable `v` which shadows function parameter, you just need to comment out that line, also pass vector by const ref:

```
void Print (const vector<int>& v){
  //vector<int> v;
  for (int i=0; i<v.size();i++){
    cout << v[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would i call that from main? void Print(vector<int> v)?

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass by const reference and remove the extraneous vector.

```
void Print(const std::vector<int>& v){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i< v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Another way to print it out would be to use iterators like so:

```
void Print(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << (*it) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Or in C++11 you can do it like so:

```
void Print(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    for(auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

I don't think your `Initialize()` function works like you expect it to. It seems to just make a copy and then discards it, not modifying any values of the existing vector.

Comment: He does not _have to_ pass by const reference.

Comment: True, but it's good advice for const correctness since he isn't modifying anything in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging c++ std's 11 onwards, this could be acheived in one line as shown below.
std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const int &i) { std::cout << i; });

This code runs a for loop using std::vector iterators from begin() to end(), serially feeding the lambda/[] function the required argument to be printed.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: `int &i` should be `const int &i`. And I'd probably use a simple loop...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code. Any particular reason for using simple for loop? I would tend to agree if it were for simple arrays and complex lambdas in leu of function.